# ¿Instalación o implementación de la librería galib para c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Como puedo instalar la librería galib en c++ para visual estudio code , o visual estudio 2019
ya descargue el código desde su pagina, que tengo que hacer para configurar mi proyecto usando galib, o de manera general como tengo que configurar mi proyecto para poder usar librerias en c++